# A question related to Young symmetrizers

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

Let $T$ be an arbitrary Young tableau (i.e., filling of the diagram of an integer partition $\lambda$ of $n$ by the numbers from $1$ to $n$, each appearing once). Let $R(T)$ be the subgroup of permutations which stabilize the set partition given by the rows of $T$ and let $C(T)$ be the subgroup of permutations which stabilize the set partition given by the columns of $T$.
In the group algebra of the symmetric group $S_n$, consider
$$
P(T)=\sum_{p\in R(T)}p
$$
and
$$
N(T)=\sum_{q\in C(T)}{\rm sgn}(q)\ q\ .
$$
Depending on one's preferred convention, the usual Young symmetrizer is defined as $P(T)N(T)$ or $N(T)P(T)$.

**Question:** What is there as far as formulas/useful representations for the element $P(T)N(T)P(T)$ ?
In particular, is there a reasonable algorithm for telling if the coefficient of a given permutation is positive, negative or zero?

The last question is perhaps hopeless, in full generality, but I would be very interested in learning anything that could help, even complicated things like the Kazhdan-Lusztig basis etc. Note that coefficient of a permutation only depends on the corresponding double coset for the Young subgroup $R(T)$.

Comment: The number of permutations appearing with nonzero coefficients in $P(T) N(T) P(T)$ is (when regarded as a function of the shape of $T$) not in [FindStat](https://www.findstat.org/StatisticFinder?Domain=Cc0002). ([SageMath code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVjz0OwjAMhfeewmNbVYiFBYk7INENocpp3SpS4lSOI-D2pCkMeHvPn3_eRDMwPaOi1g59c64gF8MFYvLFKcYswUPEhQ5j8MYy6iG-vScVOw6LhLQO6BYygmD9GkQBOzBltM-7boo8oUw9GkeYXmXx_fgoAGaRGaz7_ZbZtflpIU3C4IjrDW23fovltWoOAhtuGa4oatUGjvXpG2MVyyVW95ex-QBOw0z2&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) for computing it.)

Comment: Thanks for the Sage code!

Comment: Probably you know this, but just in case: if $K$ has characteristic $p$ and $\lambda$ is $p$-regular (i.e. the multiplicity of each part of $\lambda$ is $\le p-1$) then $KS_n P(T)N(T)P(T)$ is the quotient of the Specht module $KS_n N(T)P(T)$ by its unique maximal ideal. This is the simple module canonically labelled $D^\lambda$. It is notoriously hard to pin down these modules: even the dimension of $D^\lambda$ is unknown.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I didn't know this, as I try to stay as far away as I can from nonzero characteristic...:)